# Stream in-memory data over Python Subprocess' Popen over external command

Tags: python, io, stream, subprocess, generator

**What I want to achieve**

- I want to stream on a line-by-line basis elements from a generator-like object over a external program from Python.
- Broken down i want something like `Generator -> Popen(...) -> Generator` without holding too much data in memory.

Here a working, minimal example which demonstrates what I want to achieve:

```py
    from io import StringIO
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    import time

    proc_input = StringIO("aa\nbb\ncc\ndd")
    proc = Popen(["cat"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in  proc_input:
        proc.stdin.write(line.encode())
        yield proc.stdout.readline()
        time.sleep(1)
```

**Problem**: The `proc.stdout.readline()` just blocks and doesn't show anything.

**What I already learned**:

- If the input comes from a file-like object (i.e. something which has `fileno()` implemented), I can pass this directly to stdin and avoid writing to the PIPE. But for doing so, I need first to stream the generator to a file, which I like to avoid as this seems to be a unnecessary detour. For example the following works.

```py
    import tempfile
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

    tp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
    tp.write("aa\nbb\ncc\ndd".encode())
    tp.seek(0)
    proc = Popen(["cat"], stdin=tp, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line)
```

- If I stick to writing to the PIPE object, I can resolve the problem by closing the input stream and then read from the output stream. But here I don't know where in the meantime the data lives. Cause I my generator yields GB of data, I do not want to run into memory errors.

```py
    proc_input = StringIO("aa\nbb\ncc\ndd")
    proc = Popen(["cat"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in  proc_input:
        proc.stdin.write(line.encode())
    proc.stdin.close()

    for line in proc.stdout:
            print(line)
```

**What I also tried**:

- I played around with the buffersize argument `Popen(..., bufsize=)`, but it seemed not to have any effect.
- I tried writing the input data to `io.BufferedWriter` with the hope, that Popen can digest this as an input for stdin. Also without success.

**Additional info**: I'm using Linux.

**Remarks to Comments**

It was suggested to break the input generator into chunks. This can be achieved via

```py
   def PopenStreaming(process, popen_kwargs, nlines, input):
        while input:
            proc = Popen(process, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, **popen_kwargs)
            for n, row in enumerate(input):
                proc.stdin.write(row)
                if n == nlines:
                    proc.stdin.close()
                    break
            for row in proc.stdout:
                yield row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's always possible to do what you're trying to do. The docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html say

> Warning: Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

So you're supposed to use [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), but that means waiting for the process to terminate:

> `Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)` Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

That means you would be able to use `communicate` only once, which is not what you want.

However, I *think* using a line-buffered text mode should be safe to avoid a dead-lock:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

kwargs = {
    "stdin": PIPE,
    "stdout": PIPE,
    "universal_newlines": True,  # text mode
    "bufsize": 1,  # line buffered
}

with Popen(["cat"], **kwargs) as process:
    for data in ["A\n", "B\n", "C\n"]:
        process.stdin.write(data)
        print("data sent:", data)
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        print("output received:", output)
```

If that isn't applicable in your case, maybe you can split your call into multiple smaller calls? Using `check_output` with its `input` keyword argument might also simplify your code:

```py
from subprocess import check_output
output = check_output(["cat"], input=b"something\n")
print(output)
```